# TWA(Trusted Web Activity) "Please install Chrome Stable 72 or later" Bug

Tags: google-chrome, trusted-web-activity

I'm experiencing a bug in GoogleChrome's Trusted Web Activity feature. We've launched a Progressive Web App in the app store using TWA and it runs fine on Android Version 10 (API 29). On other versions of Android it shows a toast message reading "Please install Chrome Stable 72 or later". This occurs on older and new versions of GoogleChrome.

Has anyone experienced this bug before?

When i tried to log a bug report on the Google Chrome's Github they say the best place to ask questions about TWA's is on StackOverflow.

Comment: Are you using android-browser-helper? Can you add version of the library being used and the Chrome versions installed on the device?

Comment: @andreban We are still using custom-tabs-client.

1. Android_11_API_30 - ChromeVersion: 83.0.4103.101

Comment: I just found this article written by you:
https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/android-browser-helper-migration

I guess we'll have to migrate to android-browser-helper then.

Comment: You may also want to check how to use the WebView as a fallback: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/main/demos/twa-webview-fallback